# Reusing the views in flipview in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-rt

I have a user control FooUserControl, which has a DataContext binding on BarObject. This BarObject is created from another object FooBarObject during run time.
Using FlipView I can do something like this

```
<DataTemplate>
    .....
</DataTemplate>

<FlipView  ItemsSource="{Binding BarObjectList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FooUserControl}">
</FlipView>
```

Now from what I understand if there are 100 items in BarObjectList, this will create 100 instances of FooUserControl and assign BarObject to each of the instances as their DataContext

This in my opinion is highly inefficient because now I have 100 objects floating around. 100 can also be 1000. There are two questions I have

1. Is there a better way to do this? Ideally I would like 1 or max 3 objects (1. previous, 2. current and 3. next) to be existing and on each scroll just reassign the datacontext on the user control. Is there a way to achieve this? How would I do it using DataTemplateSelector if that is the answer?
2. I know that flip view is not the best for 1000 objects. It is better to have a listview as recommended by [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh850405.aspx). Is there any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do Previous, Current, Next thing then at best you need to Databind it to a subset of the whole Dataset.  So you would need to keep track of where you're at in that Dataset, and return a List of only 3 items.  Then you will need to know when to change this index value, you can probably do it with some clever math using the SelectionChanged event in said UI Element.

A ListView is probably your best bet when you want to show a huge collection of data items.  There are numerous tutorial to load in extra items when you're at the bottom of the list as well so you don't have to load in the whole Dataset at once.

But in all seriousness, I think you need to rethink how you want to show Data to the user.  There should rarely be a case where you want the user to thumb down 1000+ elements.  There should be some filtering in your Datasource.

Take a look `<ColletionViewSource>` for a easy way to filter out your dataset.

[ColletionViewSource MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=vs.110).aspx)